# Why does this not work? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

(Python 3.4.1)

Hey, I have this simple little guess my number game in Tkinter but it doesn't work for some reason... Can anyone see why?

```
from tkinter import *
from random import random
import tkinter.messagebox

window = Tk()

def Guess():
    if int(guessnum) == int(Number):
        print("Well Done!")
        exit()
    elif int(guessnum) >= int(Number):
        print("Too big")
    elif int(guessnum) <= int(Number):
        print("Too small")



Number = (round(random() * 10))


window.title("Guess My Number")
window["padx"] = 70
window["pady"] = 20   

guessnum="1"

entryWidget=Entry(window,textvariable=guessnum).grid(row=1,column=0)

button = Button(window, text="Guess",command=Guess()).grid(row=2,column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the expected result and what are you getting?

Comment: And what does the __import *__ do?

Comment: just a guess, but should the command be a function instead of the None that function returns when you call it?

Comment: I am expecting to get the button to do the defined Guess() thing every time it is clicked but instead it runs it once at the start (Without being clicked) and then doesn't do anything afterwards when the button is clicked.

Comment: Please don't add extra questions in - it makes the answers redundant. If you have a new question, ask it, but first why not try putting a few `print`s in to see what you are actually getting first? Note that you've made the `grid` mistake I pointed out in more than one place...

Comment: Finally got it working! :D Turns out I needed guessnum in a global variable and do what jonrsharpe said. Thank you everyone! You guys are awesome! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made two classic `Tkinter` errors in one line:

```
button = Button(window, text="Guess", command=Guess()).grid(row=2,column=0) 
                                    # ^ assigned result of call to command, not 
                                    #   the actual function
                                                     # ^ assigned result of grid 
                                                     #   (None) to button rather 
                                                     #   than the Button
```

This line is equivalent to something like:

```
Guess()
_ = Button(..., command=None)
button = _.grid(...)
```

You should have done:

```
button = Button(window, text="Guess", command=Guess)
button.grid(row=2,column=0)
```

Note parentheses removed from `Guess` and `grid` call split out to separate line

Comment: Okay, I tested that but now it returns "Too Small" for every input. Thanks by the way! :D

Answer (score 0):

The testvariable option must be an instance of the StringVar class.

```
guessnum = StringVar
guessnum.set("1")  # optional, otherwise '' I believe
```

I recommend this [tkinter reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) and use it constantly when programming tkinter widgets I am not completely familiar with, and even sometimes when answering questions here.

Comment: I have got it fully working now :D But thanks for the help :)